# Complete Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a language with the constants ${a_1},{a_2}$ and the single parameter operation $F$. Looking at the set $\Gamma=\{ \psi,\chi,\eta \}\cup\{\phi_n|n\ge1\}$ where
$\psi=\forall{x}(x\ne{F(x)})$,$\chi=\forall{x}(x={F(F(x))})$,
$\eta=F(a_1)=a_2$ and for every natural number n $\phi_n$ means that there are at least n different items that are not equal to $a_1$ or $a_2$. Prove that $Th(\Gamma)$ is complete.

I want to show that the theory is $\aleph_0$ categorical and for that I want to show that the set $\Gamma$ is categorical. I had no problem showing that the set is consistent but I have a problem showing that every two models of it are isomorphic because I'm having trouble finding a way to separate the elements of the world of the set into 2 sets to show that a bijective function from one model to another is an isomorphism

Comment: You cannot show a first order theory with infinite models is categorical. That is never true. But you can show that it is $\aleph_0$-categorical directly. In fact this follows pretty much immediately from a description of what the models of $(\psi,\chi,\eta)$ look like.

Comment: I think I know how the models look like (Z\{0},-,1,-1) for example. But I don't know how to build the isomorphism between two models. A hint would help

Comment: It might help to first ignore the axioms that say the model is infinite and consider finite models of $\psi,\chi,\eta.$ How many models up to isomorphism of size 2,3,4, 5,6? Your countably infinite model works, but the only important thing is that the elements are grouped into pairs $\pm n$ that get mapped to each other under $F.$

Comment: But I don't see how to define the sets of the pairs to create an isomorphism

Comment: Isomorphism between what? Do you have two different models? Did you try the finite case? If you want to be formal here you can define an equivalence relation in terms of the interpretation of F, each class of which will have two members.

Comment: I want to prove that every two models to this set are isomorphic. I want to define formally the mapping between the two models such that this mapping is an isomorphism. So I'm going to map a_1 to b_1 and a_2 to b_2 but I'm not sure how to map the rest of the elements

Comment: Ok, well again, my hint would be to look at how you would do that for finite models (this theory has the property that any two models of the same cardinality are isomorphic). And my other hint was to define an equivalence relation that partitions the domain into disjoint pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is essentially what [spaceisdarkgreen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/397125/spaceisdarkgreen) wrote in the comments, except at greater length.

Let $\mathfrak{C}$ and $\mathfrak{D}$ be two countable structures satisfying $\Gamma$. Note on notation: $F^\mathfrak{C}$ is the interpretation of $F$ in $\mathfrak{C}$, and $C$ is the universe of $\mathfrak{C}$. Similarly for $a_1^\mathfrak{D}$ and so on.

Note first that $F^\mathfrak{C}$ is injective. For suppose $F^\mathfrak{C}(x) = y$ and $F^\mathfrak{C}(z) = y$. Then because $\mathfrak{C} \models \chi$ we have $$x = F^\mathfrak{C}(F^\mathfrak{C}(x)) = F^\mathfrak{C}(y) = F^\mathfrak{C}(F^\mathfrak{C}(z)) = z.$$

If $c \in C$, define $[c] := \{c, F^\mathfrak{C}(c)\}$. Because $\mathfrak{C} \models \psi$, we know that $[c]$ has exactly two elements for all $c \in C$. Now if $x \in [c]$ and $x \in [c']$, then one of the following is true:
\begin{align}
c = \;&x = c' \\
c = \;&x = F^\mathfrak{C}(c') \\
c' = \;&x = F^\mathfrak{C}(c) \\
F^\mathfrak{C}(c) = \;&x = F^\mathfrak{C}(c')
\end{align}
It is easy to convince oneself that $[c] = [c']$ in all four cases. (The fourth is why we showed $F^\mathfrak{C}$ is injective.) Therefore: if $c,c' \in C$ and $[c] \cap [c'] \neq \emptyset$, then $[c]=[c']$. And obviously $c \in [c]$ for all $c \in C$. We conclude that $S_C = \{[c]:c \in C\}$ is a partition of $C$.

That's the part you seemed to be having problems with. The rest, briefly: define a partition of $D$ the exact same way, calling it $S_D$. Pick any bijection between $S_D$ and $S_C$ which sends $[a_1^\mathfrak{C}]$ to $[a_1^\mathfrak{D}]$ (at least one exists, since the partitions are both countably infinite) and call it $g$. Well-order $C$ and $D$ so that the relevant interpretation of $a_1$ is the least element in both orderings. When $c \in C$ and $d \in D$ and $g([c]) = [d]$, let $f_c$ be the order-preserving bijection between $[c]$ and $[d]$. (We want $f_c$ to be independent of the choice of representative for $[c]$, hence the orderings. There's probably a better way, but this is the first one that occurred to me.) Now it is fairly easily verified that $$f := \bigcup_{c \in C}f_c$$ is an isomorphism between $\mathfrak{C}$ and $\mathfrak{D}$.